# "Value does not fall within the expected range." error when call GAE-hosted REST service from Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, google-app-engine, rest, windows-phone-7

We're having troubles when sending http POST request to GAE-hosted script from an application in Windows Phone 7 emulator. When the callback method **HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse()** is invoked, it either hangs with timeout or crashes with exception "Value does not fall within the expected range". The flow is asynchronous, we tried HttpWebRequest based sample piece of code from MSDN, stackoverflow and other sources but they doesn't help.

Could you please give us some advice on this topic or provide some sample code for making POST requests with content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded (just like any normal web form)?

Please find the code sample below:

```
public void CallRestService() {
    var request = WebRequest.Create("https://blogboosterapi.appspot.com/") as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.BeginGetRequestStream(ar => {
                                    var request1 = (HttpWebRequest) ar.AsyncState;

                                    using (var postStream = request1.EndGetRequestStream(ar)) {
                                        var formData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ParametersToString(GetParameters()));
                                        postStream.Write(formData, 0, formData.Length);
                                        postStream.Close();
                                    }

                                    request1.BeginGetResponse(a => {
                                                                var request2 = (HttpWebRequest) a.AsyncState;
                                                                WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
                                                                WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("https://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
                                                                var response = (HttpWebResponse) request2.EndGetResponse(a);
                                                                // It fails here                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                                using (var streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream()) {
                                                                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(streamResponse)) {
                                                                        var responseString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                                                                        //
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                                }, request1);
                                    }, request);
}

private static string ParametersToString(Dictionary<string, string> parameters) {
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var parameter in parameters) {
        stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}={1}&", parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
    }
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}

public Dictionary<string, string> GetParameters() {
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    //Mandatory parameters
    parameters["methodName"] = "initUser";
    parameters["timestamp"] = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");
    parameters["language"] = "en";
    parameters["clientId"] = string.Empty;
    parameters["apiVersion"] = "1";
    //Method parameters
    parameters["clientType"] = "4";
    parameters["clientUDID"] = "1234567890";
    parameters["clientOS"] = "Windows Phone 7";
    //Optional parameters
    parameters["clientFirmware"] = "1.0";
    parameters["country"] = "ru";
    parameters["phoneNumber"] = "+791012345678";

    return parameters;
}
```

Comment: I despair when I see expression lambdas  used where a method would be clearer.

Comment: What's the full exception stacktrace? Is it an exception in the C# code, or text returned in the response?

Answer (score 0):

it could be if you have '&' or '=' without values in your Request e.g. http://smth.com?method=get&param=4& or http://smth.com?method=get&param=

Comment: i will be PhoneNumber in our case, i believe

Comment: Thanks for your replies, but it still doesn't help for me even when I populate all the values for all parameters.

I also trued calling the service without any parameters and it still not coming through. I can't even see the service call in Fiddler.

For me it looks like emulator is not able to make a service call.

Comment: @AntBevzyuk I tried same code. But I am getting error `{System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndGetResponse>b__d(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)}`. If my byte array length is large then it gives error. see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139767/windows-phone-upload-files-to-goolge-drive

Answer (score 0):

Ironically, this problem still occured after copying the code from a WP7 to a Xamarin project (WP 8.1). It also doesn't work in a Xamarin Android project, though with another exception.

After two days of research I finally gave up and moved to the `WebClient` class for my web requests, which works like a charm.